# c++20 coroutines with boost awaitable custom suspension

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20

I'm using c++20 with boost awaitable for writing async server/client.
One of the features of boost asio socket is that it is not safe to call concurrently async_write on a socket, even with 1 thread. Basically i'm trying to avoid a situation where:

calling and suspending

```cpp
co_await async_write(sock, buffer(std::string{"data to send"}), use_awaitable);
```

will not interfere with another coroutine calling `async_write` on the same socket, i.e.

```cpp
co_await async_write(sock, buffer(std::string{"data to send"}), use_awaitable);
```

Below is a pseudo code of what i'm trying to achieve. I want to create a suspension point inside of `w.Write(msg)`, enqueue the awaiter/handle, and when one `async_write` completed, that coroutine will post back to the `io_context` to resume another coroutine. the caller of `w.Write` should be suspended until resumed accordingly.

```cpp
struct Writer {
  std::deque<...> q;
  bool write_in_progress = false;
...
  awaitable<void> WriteImpl(std::string const&) {
    co_await async_write(sock, buffer(std::string{"data to send"}), use_awaitable); 

    if (!q.empty()) {
      auto awaiter = q.pop_front();
      post(ctx, []{ awaiter.coro_handle.resume(); });
    }
  }

  awaitable<void> Write(std::string const& msg) {
    if (write_in_progress) {
      auto awaiter = WriteImpl(msg);
      q.push_back(awaiter);
      co_await awaiter;
    } else {
      write_in_progress = true;
      co_await WriteImpl(msg);
    }
  }
};

Writer w{...};
co_await w.Write(msg);
```

Any suggestion on how to implement that with boost asio 1.76 and awaitable. Looking at awaitable implementation in boost, it does not support this non-linear flow, although i'm not sure...

thanks!

EDIT: Below me following up on suggestion to use `steady_timer`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <coroutine>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;

awaitable<void> Trigger(steady_timer& timer) {
    std::cout << "trigger is running" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    auto n = timer.cancel();
    std::cout << "cancelled " << n << " async operatiosns" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

awaitable<void> Process(io_context& ctx, steady_timer& timer) {
    std::cout << "from coroutine" << std::endl;
    co_spawn(ctx, Trigger(timer), detached);
    std::cout << "launched trigger" << std::endl;
    co_await timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "done waiting" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

void Test1() {
    io_context ctx;
    auto work = require(ctx.get_executor(), execution::outstanding_work.tracked);

    steady_timer timer{ctx.get_executor()};
    timer.expires_after(std::chrono::hours(24));
    co_spawn(ctx, Process(ctx, timer), detached);

    ctx.run();
}

int main() {
    Test1();

    return 0;
}
```

When i run this, I however do not see "done waiting" printed at all... am I do something wrong?

VK

Comment: Put your write function in a loop. If it has nothing to write let it co_await a timer set to timepoint max which fieres on timer.cancel(). When you have a new message push it to the queue and cancel the timer. There are an  explanation and an  example "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322884/how-to-co-await-for-a-change-in-a-variable-using-boost-coroutine-ts" on stack overflow.

Comment: added an example with `steady_timer`, any suggestions??? thanks!

Comment: Instead of "std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));" create another timer and wait for it "  steady_timer myTimer{ co_await this_coro::executor };
  myTimer.expires_after (std::chrono::seconds (3));
  co_await myTimer.async_wait (use_awaitable);". Cancel results in an exception thrown  you need to catch it. In the above example it gets swallowed in co_spawn(... , detached).

Comment: ok, got it. I had to catch the exception. I expected that ctx.run() will  exit in case of an exception... however here it's a bit different given we have an exception in the coroutine body... thanks a lot for helping out!