# Multiple coroutines using shared resource, how to synchronize them?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine

I'm trying to find a way to to synchronize access to resource shared between two coroutines. I'm using boost C++20 coroutines [Boost C++ 20 Coroutines](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/cpp20_coroutines.html)

My application is single-threaded, however, the second coroutine still affects the resource used by the first coroutine. Below you can find code snipped (in my real scenario the shared resource is not a timer, it's a boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor, but for simplicity, I used a timer here).

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::use_awaitable;

int main
{
  auto ctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
  auto timer = boost::asio::steady_timer{ctx};

  auto func = [&timer](std::chrono::seconds duration) -> awaitable<void> {
    timer.expires_after(duration);

    auto ec = boost::system::error_code{};
    co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));

    std::cout << "Error code: " << ec.message() << '\n';
  };

  co_spawn(ctx, func(std::chrono::seconds(15)), boost::asio::detached);
  co_spawn(ctx, func(std::chrono::seconds(5)), boost::asio::detached);

  ctx.run();
}
```

Here is also the output from the execution:

> @asio|1642753302.405703|0^1|in 'co_spawn_entry_point'
> (/usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/co_spawn.hpp:154)
> @asio|1642753302.405703|0*1|io_context@0x7ffd2423c2b0.execute

> @asio|1642753302.405764|0^2|in 'co_spawn_entry_point'
> (/usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/co_spawn.hpp:154)
> @asio|1642753302.405764|0*2|io_context@0x7ffd2423c2b0.execute

> @asio|1642753302.405788|>1|

> @asio|1642753302.405802|1*3|deadline_timer@0x7ffd2423c248.async_wait

> @asio|1642753302.405815|<1| @asio|1642753302.405819|>2|
> @asio|1642753302.405823|2|deadline_timer@0x7ffd2423c248.cancel
> @asio|1642753302.405829|2*4|deadline_timer@0x7ffd2423c248.async_wait

> @asio|1642753302.405835|<2| @asio|1642753302.405839|>3|ec=system:125

> Error code: Operation canceled @asio|1642753302.405870|<3|

> @asio|1642753307.405906|>4|ec=system:0 Error code: Success

> @asio|1642753307.405954|<4|
> @asio|1642753307.405967|0|deadline_timer@0x7ffd2423c248.cancel

As you can see, the timeout that was configured by the first-spawned coroutine has been canceled, when the second coroutine started execution, and I would like to avoid such a situation.
Of course in this example, I could have just used two instances of the timer, but as I mentioned above, in my case, instead of a timer I'm using a stream descriptor, so I can't just either copy it or use the second instance.

What would be a quite realiable way to synchronize access in such a case?

//EDIT
I created a piece of code that seems to act as a workaround.
Here is a snippet.

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>

using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::use_awaitable;


template<class Executor>
class AsyncMutex
{
public:
  using Timer_t = boost::asio::steady_timer;

  explicit AsyncMutex(Executor& executor)
    : executor_{executor}
  {}

  AsyncMutex(const AsyncMutex&) = delete;
  AsyncMutex(AsyncMutex&&) = delete;
  AsyncMutex& operator=(const AsyncMutex&) = delete;
  AsyncMutex& operator=(AsyncMutex&&) = delete;

  awaitable<void> async_lock()
  {
    spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: async_lock");

    if (counter_++ == 0) {
      spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: async_lock first lock, retrun");
      co_return;
    }

    spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: async_lock, aquire");

    auto ec = boost::system::error_code{};
    auto timer = Timer_t{executor_};
    timer.expires_after(boost::asio::steady_timer::duration::max());
    waiters_.push(&timer);

    spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: waiting...");
    co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
    spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: done...");
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    if (counter_.load() == 0) {
      return;
    }

    --counter_;

    if (waiters_.empty()) {
      return;
    }

    spdlog::debug("AsyncMutex: unlock");

    auto* next = waiters_.front();
    next->cancel();

    waiters_.pop();
  }

private:
  Executor& executor_;
  std::queue<Timer_t*> waiters_{};
  std::atomic<int> counter_;
};


int main() {
  spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::debug);
  auto ctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
  auto timer = boost::asio::steady_timer{ctx};
  auto mutex = AsyncMutex{ctx};

  auto func = [&timer](auto& mutex, std::chrono::seconds duration) -> awaitable<void> {

    co_await mutex.async_lock();
    spdlog::debug("Got lock");

    auto ec = boost::system::error_code{};
    timer.expires_after(duration);
    co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));

    spdlog::debug("Relaseing a lock");

    mutex.unlock();

    std::cout << "Error code: " << ec.message() << '\n';
  };

  co_spawn(ctx, func(mutex, std::chrono::seconds(30)), boost::asio::detached);
  co_spawn(ctx, func(mutex, std::chrono::seconds(15)), boost::asio::detached);

  ctx.run();
}
```

Of course - we're talking about a single-threaded environment.

Comment: Instead of creating 2 threads of execution you could create one and in the coroutine you can co_await the first and then co_await the second. If your problem is something like multiple co_await async_write on the same socket  you could use a queue where you push the messages and a couroutine which calls co_await async_write like in this example "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322884/how-to-co-await-for-a-change-in-a-variable-using-boost-coroutine-ts"

Comment: I guess that message queue would solve a problem, but then I would have to use some kind o competition handlers for each request which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Yeah. It is more a workaround. If you find a better solution let me know. If your problem is about multiple async_write I think you could improve your question by explicitly writing that and make a  complete example that reproduces the problem.